# SQLite Date and Time Datatype

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sqlite, windows-mobile

I am trying to build a nice, small database to run on a mobile application (Windows Mobile 5, if you are curious).

In the [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the Date and Time Datatype is defined as follows:

> **1.2 Date and Time Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>     Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

So, saving my `DateTime` value as either a `REAL` (float) or `INTEGER` is the same size.

What about the `TEXT` format? There are 23 characters above in the text `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`. **Is that 8-bytes per character?** If so, that is a **HUGE** waste of space to store in Text format (which is what I am currently doing).

What about the `REAL` format? Would I define a **base date** of November 24, 4714 B.C.? (I am not even sure if *Visual Studio 2008* will let me do that. I've never tried.) Then get the `TimeSpan` between **base date** and date I want, extract the number of days, and store that?

```
// is this how to declare this date?
private static readonly DateTime nov24_4714bc = new DateTime(-4714, 11, 24);

public static double GetRealDate(DateTime dateTime) {
  // FYI: subtracting dates in .NET returns a time span object
  return (dateTime - nov24_4714bc).TotalDays;
}
```

What about the `INTEGER` format? Would I define a **base date** of `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` (please tell me how to do that!), then get the `TimeSpan` between **base date** and my input date, extract the number of seconds, and store that?

```
// is this a UTC date?
private static readonly DateTime utc1970_01_01 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

public static double GetIntDate(DateTime dateTime) {
  // FYI: subtracting dates in .NET returns a time span object
  return (dateTime - nov24_4714bc).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Any help with this? I am a little confused on a few points.

Comment: pls don't store dates as text.

Comment: FYI: The `REAL` date format of Nov 24, 4714 BC throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: *"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."*

Comment: and did you need to represent 4714 BC ?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Also, it seems if I store in the UTC time and the User changes the date for whatever reason, the stored date time values are horribly screwed up. Storing "07/04/1776" for America's Independence day is wasteful, but much more reliable - unless I am missing something.

Comment: The `SQLite` doc I referenced above states they reference from 4714 BC to calculate the value for the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the `TEXT` format if "human-readability" is important.
- Use one of the numeric formats if saving space is important.

If you don't need millisecond precision, you can save space in the `TEXT` format by only including the part you do need.  There are 3 shorter formats accepted by SQLite date/time functions:

- `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (19 characters)
- `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` (16 characters)
- `YYYY-MM-DD` (10 characters)

(**NEVER** use `MM/DD/YYYY`; it's not supported, and it doesn't sort correctly.)

> Would I define a base date of November 24, 4714 B.C.? (I am not even
>   sure if Visual Studio 2008 will let me do that. I've never tried.)

You can't: `System.DateTime` only supports the years 1 to 9999.  You need to pick a different base date, and then do `(dateTime - baseDate).TotalDays + baseDateJD`, where `baseDateJD` is the Julian date of the base date.  Some reasonable choices are:

- 0001-01-01 = JD 1721425.5
- 1970-01-01 = JD 2440587.5
- 2000-01-01 = JD 2451544.5